# Make MySQL to choose the best index for a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, indexing

In MySQL 5.6 DB I have a huge SQL table of the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_requests` (
    `request_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `option_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `symbol` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `request_time` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    `request_type` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    `count` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`request_id`),
    INDEX `key_request_type_symbol` (`request_type`, `symbol`),
    INDEX `key_request_time` (`request_time`),
    INDEX `key_request_symbol` (`symbol`)
);
```

There are over 800 million records in the table with about 25,000 varieties of `symbol` field and about 100 distinct values in `request_type`. My goal is to make as quick as possible a query like:

```
SELECT tbl_requests.*
FROM tbl_requests  use index (key_request_type_symbol)
-- use index (key_request_time) -- use index (key_request_type_symbol)
WHERE (tbl_requests.request_time >= '2016-02-23' AND 
       tbl_requests.request_time <= '2016-12-23') 
AND (tbl_requests.request_type IN (0, 1, 9))  
[AND (tbl_requests.symbol = 'AAPL' ... )]
ORDER BY tbl_requests.request_time DESC, tbl_requests.request_id DESC
LIMIT 0,100;
```

with different varieties of filtering by `tbl_requests.symbol` field from no filter to a set of values to set of matching patterns to a mix and match.

What I see is that different indexes give the best performance in different cases, and MySQL is unable to guess which one will be better. For example, with no filter the fastest is `key_request_time` index (0.016 sec.) and MySQL properly selects it (result of EXPLAIN command):

> ```
> "id": 1,
> "select_type": "SIMPLE",
> "table": "tbl_requests",
> "type": "range",
> "possible_keys": "key_request_type_symbol,key_request_time",
> "key": "key_request_time",
> "key_len": "8",
> "ref": null,
> "rows": 428944675,
> "Extra": "Using index condition; Using where"
> ```

If index `key_request_type_symbol` index was used this query would take just huge amount of time (maybe hours?).

I use syntax

```
FROM tbl_requests use index (key_request_type_symbol)
```

to force using an index.

When one symbol is used in the filter

```
AND (tbl_requests.symbol = 'BAC')
```

MySQL server is choosing the same `key_request_time` index, and the query takes more than 10 sec. But if `key_request_type_symbol` index is used, the query takes about 0.7 sec. Also, when using the first index, if the query is repeated again it keeps taking over 10 sec., while when using the second index, the repeated queries take 0.1 sec. 
EXPLAIN info for `key_request_type_symbol` index:

> ```
> "id": 1,
> "select_type": "SIMPLE",
> "table": "tbl_requests",
> "type": "range",
> "possible_keys": "key_request_type_symbol",
> "key": "key_request_type_symbol",
> "key_len": "34",
> "ref": null,
> "rows": 17117,
> "Extra": "Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort"
> ```

A lot less rows, but with filesort.

It looks like in the case of `key_request_type_symbol` it matters how many matching rows are in the table. For "AMZN" symbol, rows = 79762, and time is 0.15 sec, while if using `key_request_time` index it takes 4.4 sec. But MySQL prefers it over `key_request_type_symbol`.

It is clear to see in the following example. If I use:

```
tbl_requests.symbol LIKE 'A%'
```

with `key_request_time` index it takes 0.172 sec.
with `key_request_type_symbol` index it takes 173 sec. (~1000 times slower)
rows=6367732

For:

```
tbl_requests.symbol LIKE 'AM%'
```

with `key_request_time` index it takes 0.640 sec.
with `key_request_type_symbol` index it takes 2.2 sec. (~3 times slower)
rows=838822

For:

```
tbl_requests.symbol LIKE 'AMZ%'
```

with `key_request_time` index it takes 4.5 sec.
with `key_request_type_symbol` index it takes 0.15 sec.  (~30 times faster)
rows=73083

For:

```
tbl_requests.symbol LIKE 'AMZN%'
```

with `key_request_time` index it takes 4.4 sec.
with `key_request_type_symbol` index it takes 0.15 sec.  (~30 times faster)
rows=79762

Also when using `key_request_type_symbol` index the execution gets much faster when the same symbol filter is used again while for `key_request_time` timing stays about the same.

I am going to receive a lot of queries with one symbol so I need them to be fast. But also I may receive queries filtered by many symbols. How can I force the server to pick the fastest way for me in each case?

One method I can imagine is to send EXPLAIN statement ahead and check the number of expected rows in case of `key_request_type_symbol` index, and then modify the query to use this or that index accordingly (like, if rows is over 300000, use `key_request_time`).

But maybe I am missing something? Maybe the indexes are not correct (but I couldn't find better)? It would be nice to keep the query unmodified and force MySQL to be smart enough to choose the fastest way automatically.

Comment: `IN` might take advantage of 'loose scan`; wild cards cannot.

Comment: How much time is spanned for `request_time`?  Do you intend to add to the table with more dates?  What is the typical amount of time used in a query?  (I am thinking about partitioning.)

Comment: Do those fields need to be `BIGINT` (8 bytes); does `count` need to be `INT` (4 bytes)?  Each byte-per-row saved equates to nearly 1GB of disk space (more if indexed).

Comment: Yes, id fields may go over 32-bit, and count techically may go over 64K though not likely. The database is about 700GB now and should grow by around 1TB every year. Hopefully RAM prices will keep falling down. :)

Comment: I think index by just request_time works best in some cases because of ORDER BY request_time I need to use. And, as Bill explained, after it nothing can be used.

Comment: Good idea, but not quite.  Since your `ORDER BY` has 2 columns, your index need both, also:  `INDEX(request_time, request_id)`.  Since they are both `DESC`, it will work (MySQL can scan backward).  But...

Comment: Since it cannot do any filtering on `type` or `symbol`, it will have to step over lots of rows.  Still, give it a try.  It _will_ avoid the tmp table, avoid the filesort, _and_ stop after only 100.  Beware -- some symbols/types will go fast; some will go slow.  So, don't benchmark just one case.

Comment: Again, if you decide that `(request_time, request_id)` is good, then make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and do not consider `PARTITIONing` (since it won't gain anything the way I discussed it).  Well...  `BY RANGE(type or symbol)` _may_ be worth doing.  Hmmmm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the rule you're missing about how MySQL uses indexes:

1. The left-most column(s) in your index must match the column(s) for equality comparisons (e.g. `symbol = 'AAPL'`). You can have several columns, as long as they're all doing equality conditions.
2. Then the **single next column** in the index can match a column for range comparison. A range comparison is anything other than equality. So: `<>`, `>`, `<`, `IN()`, `BETWEEN`, `LIKE` with no leading wildcard, or `IS [NOT] NULL`.
3. An index can also be used for `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`, but not if you have used an index for a range condition. Basically, you get one more column in your index, following the column(s) doing equality-tests.

Example: Suppose you have a query with the following conditions:

```
WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c > 3 AND d IN (4,5,6)
```

Suppose you have an index on (a, b, c, d) in that order. Only the a, b, c columns from the index will help the query. Since the c column is in an inequality comparison, that's the last column in the index that helps.

(Actually, InnoDB has a recent feature called "index condition pushdown" which may allow the storage engine to help a little bit more by searching for values of d, but don't count on that being as good as regular index lookups. I saw the note "Using index condition" in one of your EXPLAIN outputs, indicating that it's employing this feature. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html for more details.)

Likewise, this query would not be able to use d to avoid the filesort in the following query, because of c's inequality condition.

```
WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c > 3
ORDER BY d
```

Whereas the following would be able to use d for optimizing the sort, because once the query finds the subset of rows where c=3, then the remaining matches are naturally read in d order.

```
WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 3
ORDER BY d
```

Now for how this applies to your query:

```
WHERE (tbl_requests.request_time >= '2016-02-23' AND 
       tbl_requests.request_time <= '2016-12-23') 
AND (tbl_requests.request_type IN (0, 1, 9))  
[AND (tbl_requests.symbol = 'AAPL' ... )]
ORDER BY tbl_requests.request_time DESC, tbl_requests.request_id DESC
```

The condition on symbol is equality. That should go left-most in the index.

The conditions on request_time and request_type are both inequality. You can only benefit from one or the other in an index. Choose the one that is most *selective*—that narrows down the search the best. Add the other column to the index just in case ICP can help a little.

I'd guess that the request_time column is more selective in most cases. I see your condition is a 10-month range, which might be most of your table, but depending on the date range you choose, it could be more narrow.

Likewise, the three values 0, 1, 9 for request_type might also match most of the rows in your table. If so, then that condition would not be very selective, and I'd put that column last.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_requests ADD INDEX (symbol, request_time, request_type);
```

The order request_time happens after the inequality conditions, so there's no way to avoid filesorting the matching rows, sorry.

Comment: This is useful information. Since I mentioned I have a limited number of `request_type`s (~100), I can always switch IN (0, 1, 9) to (request_type = 0 OR request_type = 1 OR request_type = 9). Will it change it to an equality condition? But I can't guarantee an equality condition for `symbol` since I need to use LIKE operator sometimes. Also, I need to support the case when  `symbol` condition is missing (for all symbols case). Should then my best index be (request_type, symbol) as it is?

Comment: It counts as a range condition if you're trying to search for multiple values of request_type, regardless of what syntax you use. Equality condition means you're searching for one specific value from the index. Range condition means you're searching for multiple values from the index.

Comment: Defining your index with symbol after request_type means the search for symbol will definitely *not* use the index for the symbol search, since it's after the column used for a range condition. Except maybe some help from ICP.

Comment: In Bill's first example, might `INDEX(a, b, d, c)` use a "loose scan"?

Comment: @VladimirShutow - Your `OR` example is turned into `IN` by the Optimizer, so they are equivalent.  (Switching to `UNION` of multiple `SELECTs` is another matter.)

Comment: @RickJames, as far as I know, loose index scans only applies to GROUP BY queries. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 2):

Have **several indexes**:

```
(        request_type, request_time)
(symbol,               request_time)
(symbol, request_type, request_time)
```

I am assuming `symbol=`, not `LIKE` or `IN`.  These will handle most of the cases, including those where you are missing some column and/or using a single type in `IN()`.  `IN(single-item)` turns into `=` which is eminently more optimizable than `IN(...)`.

That brings up another possibility:  You *may* get better performance with **`UNION`** instead of `IN`.

Seems like you would typically be getting back **thousands** of rows (before the `LIMIT`); if so, what will you be doing with them?  I ask because sometimes optimization techniques aimed at that can help even more.  [*Pagination via OFFSET*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) is one evil that comes to mind.

You are using InnoDB, correct?  If not,you should be.

**`request_id`** is never used?  Then why have it?  Especially why have it as the PK. (OK, OK, I insist on PK for InnoDB tables; I'll get to that.)  Is some combination of columns unique?  If so, promote that to be the PK.

If you don't have any combination that can safely be the **Primary Key** (`DATETIME(6)`, though precise, should not be trusted), then keep `request_id` but do the following:

```
PRIMARY KEY (..., request_id),
INDEX(request_id)  -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

Now the *data*, not just some secondary index, is in the order given by the PK.  We can take advantage of such to get "locality of reference" -- that will cut back on I/O (are you IO-bound some of the time?), thereby significantly speeding up queries.  Before discussing what column(s) to put in `...`, *and* what order to put them in, we need a better feel for your queries.  Which column is typically most selective?  Do you often have only one item in `IN`?  Etc.

Do you need *all* the columns (`SELECT *`)?  If not, we need to talk about **covering** indexes.

With more info about the distribution of values and queries, we can discuss whether it makes sense to use **PARTITIONing**.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I will keep on trying to add and try more indexes but it takes a while on a big table and I thought of cutting some time by learning the theory. Actually, using UNION is a great suggestion, I can use just one request_type in each and thus applying type_time key to it. Something like (SELECT .... WHERE type=1... ORDER ... LIMIT 100) UNION ALL (SELECT .... WHERE type=2... ORDER ... LIMIT 100) ORDER ... LIMIT 100 should work.

Comment: I do use request_id and it's unique, I don't use AUTO_INCREMENT. This is a simplified query I used for the showcase since in a more complex one the core problem is the same.

Comment: If you don't have `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`, then add multiple indexes in a single `ALTER TABLE`; it is faster.

Comment: Yes, that `UNION` is how to do it.  Now that you have `type=`, heed Karwin's Answer and put `type` among the `=` columns at the  beginning of the index.  Beware of `OFFSET`, it gets trickier.

Comment: If `request_id` does not need the uniqueness _constraint_, then do not use `UNIQUE`; it adds unnecessary overhead.  Hence, my PK+index comment still applies.

Comment: Since request_id is unique, any combination of the columns including it will be unique, right? Or you are asking about all unique columns? Then only request_id is unique. But why also creating an index on PK column? Can't PK be used as an index?

Comment: Correct -- hence my inclusion at the end of the PK.

Comment: Also I need to mention that switching to SSD made the whole difference in using this DB (just that one table uses about 200GB with indexes). And yes, I used InnoDB packed. Thinking of also trying TocuDB at some time.

Comment: The PK is a unique index (MySQL-specific extension) and is an index.  With InnoDB, the PK is also "clustered" with the data.  That is, consecutive values in the PK are consecutively stored in the data.  This is sometimes a big performance boost.

Comment: How big is the table (GB)?  How much RAM?  If the data+indexes is between ram size and 10 times that big, then TokuDB's compression may put you in a sweet spot where it can live in RAM.  But once it gets bigger than RAM, that advantage is gone.  Then you pay for Toku's large block size and CPU decompression.  (Still, it _may_ be better.)

Comment: TokuDB is included in MariaDB 10.x; that may be the best way to move to it.  All your existing InnoDB code will still work, while you experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Since your table will quickly out-strip RAM (1TB/year growth), I will propose a `PARTITION` method that, in some situations, will be beneficial.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_requests (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(..., request_time, request_id),
    INDEX(...), ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(request_time)) PARTITIONS (
    ... );
```

- It is partitioned by the date field.
- The PK must include `request_time`; put it near the end.
- secondary keys may *end* with `request_time`, but only if you are likely to get to that column.  That is, if there are already range columns before it, don't waste space by including it.
- Keep the number of partitions under 50 (until you upgrade to 8.0).  Since this smells like stock quotes, you could probably partition by months.  But if you already have data going back multiple years, then partition old data (before 2016) by year, newer data by month.  (But use `TO_DAYS()`.)  Since `BY RANGE` gives you control over such, there is no problem mixing years and days.
- *If* many of the queries reference only 'recent' data, the partitioning will have the latest few partitions mostly cached; the rest mostly on disk.  This may be the main performance benefit.
- You have multiple "dimensions" in your Data Warehouse, the date *may* be the best dimension to relegate to `PARTITIONing`.
- The next-best dimension should be relegated to the *first* column of the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Otherwise, the `PRIMARY KEY` and secondary keys should be as discussed in other answers.
- Do not even consider `SUBPARTITION` or `HASH`; they are (in my opinion) useless for performance.
- More partitioning discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

**---OR---**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_requests (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(request_time, request_id),
    INDEX(...), ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY RANGE(type? symbol?) PARTITIONS (
    ... );
```

- It is partitioned by the `type` or `symbol`.  If `LIKE 'AM%'` is common, then use symbol.  Otherwise, I don't have an opinion.
- The PK is based on the 2-column `ORDER BY`.  This gives pretty good 'locality of reference'.
- Keep the number of partitions under 50 (until you upgrade to 8.0).  If using `type`, then pick the ranges based on some kind of weighting -- tiny partitions are not necessarily good.  If based on symbol, then the 28 partitions may be "good enough": 1 per first letter, plus extra on front and back.
- *If* many of the queries reference only 'recent' data, the "end" of the *data* in each partition will tend to be cached.  This may be the main performance benefit.
- If partitioning on `type`, then add `INDEX(symbol, request_time, request_id)` so that the `symbol=constant` will be very well optimized.
- If partitioning on `symbol`, add `INDEX(type, request_time, request_id)` so that `type=constant` is optimized.
- Note:  You may not need any other secondary indexes -- thereby saving a lot of disk space.  (OK, partitioning wastes some space.)